# How to use CURDATE() as column name

Tags: mysql, sql

HERE IS MY QUERY ( It doesn't work.)

```
SELECT 
  SUM(last_access_date > CURDATE() and last_access_date < CURDATE()+1) as CURDATE(),
  SUM(last_access_date > CURDATE()-1 and last_access_date < CURDATE()) as CURDATE()-1,
  SUM(last_access_date > CURDATE()-2 and last_access_date < CURDATE()-1) as CURDATE()-2,
  SUM(last_access_date > CURDATE()-3 and last_access_date < CURDATE()-2) as CURDATE()-3,
  SUM(last_access_date > CURDATE()-4 and last_access_date < CURDATE()-3) as CURDATE()-4,
  SUM(last_access_date > CURDATE()-5 and last_access_date < CURDATE()-4) as CURDATE()-5,
  SUM(last_access_date > CURDATE()-6 and last_access_date < CURDATE()-5) as CURDATE()-6
FROM MYTABLE
```

I Want to see like that.

[image]

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: @Strawberry Could you explain more?

Comment: @zynkn Strawberry is saying that if you're using an app language like PHP or Java, it would be easier to just query your data and then generate this output there.

Comment: @JitendraSoftgrid `SUM` is not the problem. I want to use date as column name

Comment: You have to explicitly give the column name you can't give `CURDATE() +1` be a name

Comment: @D-Shih I know.. Whenever I use that query I want to see the data standardise by today

Comment: @D-shih If today is `2018-04-30`, what I want to see the column name is `2018-04-30`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really a requirement which would be best solved by using your view technology to handle, e.g. something like PHP or maybe Java.  In such an app language, it is relatively easy to take a result set and format it the way you want.

That being said, if you require your exact output in MySQL, it is possible, but with a fairly large union query:

```
SELECT
    c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-%m-%d') AS c1,
        DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE()-1, '%Y-%m-%d') AS c2,
        DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE()-2, '%Y-%m-%d') AS c3,
        DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE()-3, '%Y-%m-%d') AS c4,
        DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE()-4, '%Y-%m-%d') AS c5,
        DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE()-5, '%Y-%m-%d') AS c6,
        DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE()-6, '%Y-%m-%d') AS c7,
        0 AS position
    FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        (SELECT CAST(SUM(last_access_date > CURDATE() AND last_access_date < CURDATE()+1) AS CHAR(50))),
        (SELECT CAST(SUM(last_access_date > CURDATE()-1 and last_access_date < CURDATE()) AS CHAR(50))),
        (SELECT CAST(SUM(last_access_date > CURDATE()-2 and last_access_date < CURDATE()-1) AS CHAR(50))),
        (SELECT CAST(SUM(last_access_date > CURDATE()-3 and last_access_date < CURDATE()-2) AS CHAR(50))),
        (SELECT CAST(SUM(last_access_date > CURDATE()-4 and last_access_date < CURDATE()-3) AS CHAR(50))),
        (SELECT CAST(SUM(last_access_date > CURDATE()-5 and last_access_date < CURDATE()-4) AS CHAR(50))),
        (SELECT CAST(SUM(last_access_date > CURDATE()-6 and last_access_date < CURDATE()-5) AS CHAR(50))),
        1
    FROM MYTABLE
) t
ORDER BY position;
```

I don't have your exact data in front of me, but I managed to setup a demo with dummy sum values, and this is what the output looks like:

[image]

### Demo

Comment: Thank you for your answer. :) I will try to solve with js,

Comment: @zynkn I gave you a demo which you can try.  Again, it is possible to do this in pure MySQL, but JavaScript is probably a better place to do it.